# Git parent repository

Tags: android, git, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, git-submodules

I am wondering how to manage kind of git "parent" repository.

I started with Android project, where couple of first commits are preparing a project - additional Gradle plugins, dynamic versioning, etc.
Now I would like to externalize it to separate repository, which can be a kind of the template for new projects but also a common place to maintain a project configuration like Gradle and plugins versions, build and sonar configuration, etc. So when I change anything common to all projects, I can easily merge it to all "child" projects.

I thought about few approaches:

- fork from the parent project - not really sure, because it is not a real fork
- separate projects with remote to parent or parent with remotes to children and pull/push
- git submodules it is rather not helpful in this case, or I am wrong?
- others?
- others...?

Comment: I’d try separate repositories with two remotes: one its own and one looking to the “parent” repo. Not sure how it will work in practice however.